# I need to get the anchor & ambressent values from url in Asp.netCore MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For Example;
I have Url : https://slb.renault.in/connector/Home/Index#token=bearer&access_token=eysdkekxdjdn.

I need after # symbol data from above url in ASP.NET core MVC

I have tried with httpcontext.Request.GetdisplayUrl().
It gave me till https://slb.renault.in/connector/Home/Index.

But after anchor it is not giving

Please help me how to get it ?